# getRange outputting "Range" instead of values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm making a code that copies certain data from our EOD worksheet, and copy/pasting the data onto another sheet, which acts as a summary.

I've got most of the code already working, but running into trouble with the getRange output.  It just shows "Range" in the cell instead of my input, which should all be numbers.

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = [];
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SnapshotSpreadsheet');
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,2);
  source.push(sheet.getRange('B20'));
  source.push(sheet.getRange('E20:F20'));
  source.push(sheet.getRange('H20'));
  source.push(sheet.getRange ('J20:I20'));
  source.push(sheet.getRange ('M18'));
  source.push(sheet.getRange ('K20'));
  source.push(insertDate());
  destSheet.getRange(2,1,1,7).setValues([source]);
```

I've included just the portion that is causing the issue. I defined source as an array, and stored values into the array, then just called for them to be output on the next available line. Everything seems to be lining up alright, just the values are all "Range".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getValue()` (if single cell) or `getValues()` (if multiple cells) to get the content of those ranges.

Cfr https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()

Comment: Thank you so much! As you could have guessed, I'm a noob at this, so I super appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do `.getValues()` for it to return the values of the cells

```
var values = sheet.getRange('E20:F20').getValues();
```

This returns a Two Dimensional array of values, so you'll have to work around that in your code. For example the line of code I just wrote would be an array like

`[[Value at E20, Value at F20]]`

so in order to access the Value at E20, you would call `values[0][0]` or for Value at F20, - `values[0][1]`

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was super clear, and really helped out!